# Function in classes Python

Tags: python, function, class

I'm trying to pass some values to initialize a class:

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, name, age, weight, height, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height
        self.sex = sex
```

This is where I try to use them:

```
def calories():
    
    if  self.sex == "Man":
        #for Man
        kcal = float((10 * self.weight) + (6.26 * self.height) - (5 * self.age) + 5)
    else:    
        #for Wman
        kcal = float(655 + (9.6 * self.weight) + (1.8 * self.height) - (4.7 * self.age))

    return round(kcal,2)
```

I tried `self.sex`, `sex`, `User.sex`, `super.sex` and every single time I got an error.

```
     if  super.sex == "Man":
AttributeError: type object 'super' has no attribute 'sex'
```

The only solution I've found was something like this:

```
def calories(object):
```

and to use `object.sex`, `object.age` etc.
Is the above method correct? Or am I doing something wrong?

instantiate the object

```
    user = get_user()
    print(user)

    kcal = User.calories()
```

`

Comment: Is `calories` supposed to be a method of the class?  If so, you need to make the first argument `self` so that you can refer to the instance.  Otherwise your references to `self` will fail.

Comment: Is `calories` defined inside the body of the class?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: kcal = User.calories()
TypeError: User.calories() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Did you mean: `kcal = user.calories()`?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73927500/edit) your post to add information like the error traceback.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading the section about classes in some good Python tutorial, that would probably help you a lot to understand these notions. See a list at https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F . [The section about classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) in the official tutorial is a good, useful read too.

Comment: `self` is not a special word in python, it's just a convention for a name for the first input of a method, which would normally be called with dot notation. So, `def calories():` defines a function with no arguments, but then you try to use `self` without defining it. `def calories(self):` would do the trick.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly I posted lower, that I did not help at all

Answer (score 1):

What you meant to write was this:

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, age, weight, height, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height
        self.sex = sex

    def calories(self):
        if  self.sex == "Man":
            kcal = float((10 * self.weight) + (6.26 * self.height) - (5 * self.age) + 5)
        else:    
            kcal = float(655 + (9.6 * self.weight) + (1.8 * self.height) - (4.7 * self.age))

        return round(kcal,2)

user = User('Jon', 1, 1, 1, 'Man')
print(user.calories())
```

Note how `calories()` is defined with `self` as the first (and only) parameter, which is used to access all the member attributes defined in `__init__()`

Comment: I tried it befor and I got an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Nowy folder\gymrat2.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Nowy folder\gymrat2.py", line 9, in main
    kcal = User.calories()
TypeError: User.calories() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: `"I tried it befor"`  Well, obviously not. Your error says: `kcal = User.calories()` and not what my answer does.

Comment: I I just have added instantiate the object and still  I have an error                                             " Josh 23 78 178 Male
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Nowy folder\gymrat2.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Nowy folder\gymrat2.py", line 9, in main
    kcal = User.calories()
TypeError: User.calories() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' "

Answer (score 0):

When you have a method on a class in python, the first parameter must be `self`. Any parameter you provide will act in the same way, which is why when you tried it with `object` it worked.

```
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self, my_input):
        self.some_variable = my_input

    def some_function(self):
        print(self.some_variable)
```

Note that in your `__init__` class you have this `self` variable, and do not receive the error you saw in your `calories()` class.

Note also that `self` is not special in any way, it's just a 'convention' for the first variable of a class method, specifically because it gets 'ignored' when you are calling the method:

```
 obj = SomeClass("Hello")
 obj.some_function()  # No variable is passed here!
```

Despite not passing a variable, this still works. The `self` we defined in the method refers to the object itself, and will be automatically inserted by the interpreter when the method is called.

Comment: '   def calories(self):
        
        if  self.sex == "Man":
            #for Man
            kcal = float((10 * self.weight) + (6.26 * self.height) - (5 * self.age) + 5)
        else:    
            #for Wman
            kcal = float(655 + (9.6 * self.weight) + (1.8 * self.height) - (4.7 * self.age))

        return round(kcal,2)'

Comment: I was trying like that but I got error as well Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Nowy folder\gymrat2.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Nowy folder\gymrat2.py", line 9, in main
    kcal = User.calories(user)
TypeError: User.calories() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: It's real hard to know if that Python is going to work given that it cares about whitespace, but the error you're getting is a new one and *probably* because you're calling `my_obj.calories(some_var)` when it's defined as `def calories(self)`. The first parameter, because it's a class method, doesn't 'count'. So when you try to pass in a variable you get that error. You should just look up that error on SO though for a better explanation.

Comment: @MateuszPlsz As a recommendation, ditch all the actual calculations. Find a *minimal* example of what is breaking for you before you try to add that complexity. Here, almost everything happening in the function doesn't matter - which is why in my code above I elided it.

Comment: 1) instantiate the object: `some_user = User(foo, bar, baz)`. 2) do `kcal = some_user.calories()`. Note you don't need to call the method from the class (like `User.calories` since the dot notation is telling python this is a method defined for the calss of `some_user` and its taking that instance as first argument (so no need to put anything inside the parentheses).

Comment: Adding an example to your original question of **how** you instantiate the object and call the method will help a lot...

Comment: I added how I instantiate the object. So as you can see I dont put anythinq in parentheses. Still I get an error                                                                                     
"  Josh 23 78 178 Male
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Nowy folder\gymrat2.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Nowy folder\gymrat2.py", line 9, in main
    kcal = User.calories()
TypeError: User.calories() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' "

Comment: `get_user()` is *not* an object instantiation, it is a function call that is, presumably, returning an object that is instantiated. Honestly, without the full, properly formatted code you're using and the stack trace of the error you're getting (not in a comment - that's very hard to parse correctly), this will be impossible to debug for you in a manner than is clearer than we've already done here. I again encourage you to re-read about Python objects and methods, because these errors are *very* common. SO has plenty of answers regarding them.